# Show that $(1+x)^{1-x}(1-x)^{1+x}<1$

Tags: inequality

If $x$ is a positive proper fraction. Prove that $$(1+x)^{1-x}(1-x)^{1+x}<1$$

Actually this question has two parts I can't do the $1^{st}$ part but the $2^{nd}$ part was quite easy with respect to the $1^{st}$ one. The $2^{nd}$ was to show that $$a^bb^a<(\frac{a+b}{2})^{a+b} $$ I observe that if $1^{st}$ is true then if I will put $$x=\frac{a-b}{a+b}$$ the equation of part $1^{st}$ will take the form $$a^bb^a<(\frac{a+b}{2})^{a+b} $$ and hence proved but I am unable to prove that $(1+x)^{1-x}(1-x)^{1+x}<1$

Comment: Is this question really belongs to sequences and series

Comment: @John: I don't see it.

Comment: Actually It does.

Comment: This is a question of sequences and series

Comment: The question may come from a sequences and series situation, but as written, it doesn't seem to relate sequences and series.

Comment: Actually I also couldn't understand this, but it belongs to sequences and series

Comment: Apply logarithm

Comment: @HarshKumar Could you provide some reasoning behind _why_ you believe it belongs there?

Comment: I tried to use logarithm series in this and it worked.

Comment: @HarshKumar: there is nothing about sequences or series in this question. If you were to show that you used series, then perhaps it might merit the [sequences-and-series] tag, but as it stands, it no more should have that tag than the [logarithms] tag because an answer used logarithms.

Comment: @HarshKumar: the description of the [sequences-and-series] tag says "For questions about recurrence relations, convergence tests, and identifying sequences." The question has nothing to do with this. Since the question has not been modified to include anything relating it to this tag, I am removing the tag. If the question is amended to include some relation to [sequences-and-series], the tag might apply.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sketch:
$$
(1+x)^{1-x}(1-x)^{1+x}=(1+x)^{1-x}(1-x)^{1-x}(1-x)^{2x}=(1-x^2)^{1-x}(1-x)^{2x}
$$
Since both $1-x^2<1$ and $1-x<1$ (and the exponents are positive), this is a product of terms less than $1$.

Answer (score 5):

I would use here the inequality
$(1 + x) \leqslant e^x$.
This gives us
\begin{split}
(1+x)^{1-x}(1-x)^{1+x} &\leqslant (e^x)^{1-x}(e^{-x})^{1+x} \\
&= e^{x-x^2}e^{-x-x^2} \\
&= e^{-2x^2} \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{2x^2} \\
&< 1,\quad x>0
\end{split}

Answer (score 1):

Since $\log$ is concave,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1-x}2\log(1+x)+\frac{1+x}2\log(1-x)
&\le\log\left(\frac{1-x}2(1+x)+\frac{1+x}2(1-x)\right)\\
&=\log\left(1-x^2\right)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\color{#090}{(1+x)^{1-x}(1-x)^{1+x}}\le\color{#C00}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}
$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We just need prove:$$(1-x)\ln{(1+x)}+(1+x)\ln{(1-x)}<0$$ $$\Longleftrightarrow \frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{1+x}+\frac{\ln{(1-x)}}{1-x}<0$$ 
So,you need a function:$$f(x)=\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{1+x}$$ I hope its useful for you